# When tangling, how to reference code-blocks from different file?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-ref, tangle

When tangling, I want to use/refer to code-blocks from different file.

---

Suppose `/tmp/1.org` file below that contains code block named `code_block_in_1_org` (that I want to use later).

```org
* This is ~1.org~ file:

#+name: code_block_in_1_org
#+begin_src python :noweb yes
import pandas as pd
#+end_src
```

And then, I want to use `code_block_in_1_org` block in different file (`/tmp/2.org` - `the_final_code_block`):

```org
#+INCLUDE: "/tmp/1.org"           

* This is the ~/tmp/2.org~ file
#+caption: Local Code Block
#+name: code_block_local
#+begin_src python :noweb yes
import numpy as np
#+end_src

#+caption: The Final Code Block
#+name: the_final_code_block
#+begin_src python :results output :tangle output.py :noweb yes
<<code_block_in_1_org>>      # referencing from 1.org
<<code_block_local>>         # referencing from within 2.org
#+end_src
```

When I export `2.org` to `LaTeX PDF` everything works fine:
[image]

---

**Problem**: when I `org-babel-tangle` in `2.org` the output `output.py` file doesn't contain the `code_block_in_1_org` part:

```py
# referencing from 1.org
import numpy as np         # referencing from within 2.org
```

---

**Question:**

- How to refer to code-block from different file when tangling the code?
- And, why does it work when Exporting PDF, and not when tangling?

Comment: 1. I don't know for sure, but I don't see any evidence that it is possible; 2. because `#+INCLUDE`s are processed on export, but are not processed on tangle - I'd suggest that you send an RFE to the mailing list. One possible hack is to proceed as in export: copy the file contents into a temp buffer, process the includes in the temp buffer and then tangle from that buffer to the output file.

Comment: Sorry, what's a `RFE`? (is this a tag for Request-Feature?)

Comment: Sorry -RFE stands for "Request For Enhancement".

Comment: I've sent it, If anyone interested, you can see it [here](https://list.orgmode.org/87cz3vhfm5.fsf@gmail.com/T/#u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this can be done via `org-babel-lob-ingest` functions. (see the mail [reply](https://list.orgmode.org/87cz3vhfm5.fsf@gmail.com/T/#m65fba4448547e1cff8e7c1364da826a66495ca5b)).

From [manual-16.12:](https://orgmode.org/manual/Library-of-Babel.html)

> For any user to add code to the library, first save the code in regular code blocks of an Org file, and then load the Org file with org-babel-lob-ingest, which is bound to C-c C-v i.

Just adding `/tmp/1.org` via `M-x org-babel-lob-ingest`, or `(org-babel-lob-ingest "/tmp/1.org")` will load code-blocks in that file. And then, tangling `/tmp/2.org` does include code-blocks from the other file.